# Merge suggestion: [save] and [export]

Tags: discussion, tags

I was checking [one of the new questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95123/how-to-resize-artwork-for-web-as-small-medium-and-large-sizes) and saw it's tagged [save](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save). I think it's basically the same as [export](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export). I know saving and exporting is not the same but:

- Most of the questions are about saving files in a different format, which is exporting;
- a lot of the questions are tagged with both tags, which seems unnecessarily redundant;
- a bunch of questions ask about "Save for Web" or "Save as" which is also exporting!
- I don't think it's such an important concept that we need differentiation with 2 tags, or that we need a tag when asking about saving PSD files (usually the question already includes other more useful tags for the context);
- I generally dislike the sound of [save](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save)? It's not very design-y 
  <sub><sup>(ok maybe ignore this reason)</sup></sub>.

Shall we merge them?

Comment: While they're different terms in general, in terms of what *could* be asked about I can only think of tech support questions that deal with `save` only and not `export`. So I'm for synonymizing "save" with "export"

Comment: Funny how in " unnecessarily redundant" the unnecessarily  is redundant

Comment: Oh, and I'm also for synonymizing them rather than merging

Comment: I save many copies and versions of my working files. I save a final version and stages along the way. These files are rarely seen by others. What they see are my exports. I "save for web" to make the client file or the image to go in a website. While "saving for web" I do the scaling and file selecting and resolution settings. Only when exporting do I configure the file correctly for display. My working file gets saved all the time but it is not ready to display. For me save and export are very different workflows, although export can be referred to as "saving as" "saving out" or "saving to".

Comment: So, depending on the question it may still be important to distinguish between saving and exporting.

Comment: @PieBie the "unnecessarily redundant" was meant as a joke :)

Comment: @Webster I agree those are different actions but I don't think we need them both for GD.SE questions for the reasons mentioned and what Zach Saucier said.

Comment: @Luciano: redundancy isn't necessarily unnecessary, so we're both fools :D

Answer (score 2):

Nope... export converts formats for many application and involved specific settings to get specific results.

Save/Save as involved selection of options for *that* application, not others.

I.E. How do I save an Illustrator file for press? vs How do I export an Illustrator file for web?

Or... You **can't** "save" a video with Photoshop... but you **can** "export" a video.

Two completely different answers.

Sure *users* may mistakenly use "save" when they *mean "export" or vice versa. But to me the tags are unique indicators if a user is knowledgable enough to choose the correct tag.

Comment: Yes, but even in your Illustrator example save a file for press involves specific settings to get specific results. In the end the Save tag gets used mostly for questions like "how to save as emf from Inkscape" or "how to save for web from Illustrator", both of which are about exporting files. Or tech support about file sizes...

Comment: If only everyone understood the nuanced difference between the two functions. I could've sworn you and I discussed this on a meta post a long time ago too, or maybe it was Import? Ah well, couldn't find it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

While they're different terms in general, in terms of what could be asked about I can only think of tech support questions that deal with save only and not export. If anyone can find a good, on topic question (or multiple) that deals with saving and not exporting, I'd happily recant this opinion.

I'm for *synonymizing* "save" with "export".

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29933/force-indesign-to-backup-autosave-keep-backup-copy

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41027/why-does-my-psd-file-contain-only-one-layer-after-saving-a-project-from-photosho

Comment: @Ryan Both of those seems like tech support questions to me, but I realize that GD allows some relevant tech support questions